# sublime-text installation warning in ubuntu 18.04 LTS using snap

Tags: snap, sublime-text

```
$ sudo snap install sublime-text 
error: This revision of snap "sublime-text" was published using classic confinement and thus may
       perform arbitrary system changes outside of the security sandbox that snaps are usually
       confined to, which may put your system at risk.

       If you understand and want to proceed repeat the command including --classic.
```

I don't understand this warning, whether I should install this or not.

When I type `$ subl` it results

```
$ subl

Command 'subl' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo snap install sublime-text
```

But `sudo snap install sublime-text` doesn't install.

Answer (score 4):

Referring to [snaps.io documents](https://docs.snapcraft.io/reference/confinement):

> A snap in classic confinement behaves as a traditionally packaged
>   application, with full access to the system. As opposed to strict and
>   devmode, what a classic snap sees as “/” is the host system’s “/” and
>   not the core snap’s “/”.

**TL;DR**: It acts like usual `.deb` packages with access to read and write system's files, unlike usual snap packages which is entirely isolated from system minus allowed places.

If you want to install, pass option `--classic` at the command line, so it looks like:

```
sudo snap install sublime-text --classic
```

Installing it or not is entirely your choice.